# Alexa spoke in a foreign language without prompt

Tags: alexa

Today totally freaked me out.  I was in a back bedroom and started walking down the hallway to our kitchen where Alexa sits.  I heard a voice from the kitchen (I was alone at home and had been for 2 days), rounded the corner to hear her speaking in a foreign language for the length of a normal sentence.  Then stopped. I asked Alexa - what did you just say - her response was she didn't understand.  Needless to say that freaked me out.  No one in my home speaks anything other than English!

How can this be?

Comment: I'm assuming you have ruled out any obvious things, like someone playing a practical joke or Alexa overhearing an advertisement on TV or radio?

Comment: why would that freak you out? ... technology is not 100% reliable

Comment: Sometimes, it hears things out of normal house sounds. Go look at the voice history like this:  
https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GHXNJNLTRWCTBBGW   
While you're in the privacy settings, also review the history of detected sounds.  
You'll atleast know what she thought she heard.  
Maybe you'll find that when the wind blows a certain way, the tree next to your house creaks a certain sound that she thinks is a request for a certain song in a foreign language ! 
Let us know what you found ! 
It'll be fun, I think.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop that looks like an answer to me